# Does the state obtained flipping $a,b$ in the state $(a,b)^T$ have a name?

Tags: quantum-state, textbook-and-exercises

Suppose we have a qubit with a state vector of $\begin{pmatrix}
a \\
b
\end{pmatrix}
$.
If we flip $a$ with $b$ does the new qubit has a name in relation to the first qubit?

Answer (score 3):

I agree that, in your context, "negate" doesn't mean to flip the sign of the vector but rather to flip the entries in the vector, much as the negation of logical `0` is logical `1` (or the negation of **FALSE** is **TRUE**).

But nonetheless it's kind of an interesting bit of a type issue that you might be making in mixing the qubit with the wavefunction of the qubit - the qubit is *physical* and is what it is. The qubit doesn't change as there's still only one of them, much as a [flip-flop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)) doesn't stop being a flip-flop or doesn't become a new flip-flop depending on what's stored in it.

For example, let a first variable $a$ be stored in a flip-flop - call it Cerise's flip-flop.  Let Cerise's flip-flop stores $a$ as `0`.  When the value of Cerise's flip-flop is negated as $\bar a$ Cerise's *flip-flop* doesn't change but the value *stored* in the flip-flop changes to, say, `1`.

In the case of a qubit - call it Cerise's qubit - we can have the qubit initially store a wavefunction, e.g., $|\psi\rangle$, as $\begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \end{pmatrix}$. If the qubit's wavefunction changes to $\begin{pmatrix} b \\ a \end{pmatrix}$, it would still be Cerise's qubit.

Nonetheless you can always refer to the new *state* of Cerise's qubit as $X|\psi\rangle$, because the [Pauli-$X$ gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_logic_gate) flips the entries in the computational basis. Depending on the context, the $X$ gate is also referred to as the NOT gate.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149297/discussion-on-answer-by-mark-spinelli-does-the-state-obtained-flipping-a-b-in); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.